# Passing javascript variable into php code without using GET parameters?

Tags: php, javascript, variables

is there any way to get js variable in php, i try something funny like this:

```
<script>
var x = "random text";
alert("aaa<?php echo md5(;?>"+x+"<?php); ?>");
</script>
```

Of course it gives me error.

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `')'' in X:XXX\index.php on line XXX
```

If there is a way without refreshing the page or using GET parameters, please let me know. Thanks

EDIT:

What I am trying to do is: hash(md5 inside php) the javascript variable.

Comment: You cannot do this, what you're doing is embedding PHP into your JavaScript, and that just doesn't work. Best bet would be to AJAX it to return the md5.

Comment: @ILMV: or just use one of the JavaScript-based MD5 solutions out there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP runs at the server, JavaScript runs at the client (browser).  The only way you can pass a variable from JavaScript to PHP is sending it via an AJAX request.

There are [several MD5 solutions out there](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+md5) for JavaScript, but it's not the same if you want the variable hashed before it reaches the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it like that because PHP builds the page before javascript is initialized.  You'll have to do an AJAX request.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = "random text"
$.post('md5.php', {md5:x}, function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
</script>

<?php
  echo md5($_POST['md5']);
?>
```

Or..

```
function md5(e){function k(h,i){var g=[h&2147483648,i&2147483648,h&1073741824,i&1073741824,(h&1073741823)+(i&1073741823)];if(g[2]&g[3])return g[4]^2147483648^g[0]^g[1];return g[2]|g[3]?g[4]&1073741824?g[4]^3221225472^g[0]^g[1]:g[4]^1073741824^g[0]^g[1]:g[4]^g[0]^g[1]}function n(h,i,g,j,s,m,o){h=k(h,k(k(i&g|~i&j,s),o));return k(h<<m|h>>>32-m,i)}function p(h,i,g,j,s,m,o){h=k(h,k(k(i&j|g&~j,s),o));return k(h<<m|h>>>32-m,i)}function q(h,i,g,j,s,m,o){h=k(h,k(k(i^g^j,s),o));return k(h<<m|h>>>32-m,i)}function r(h,i,g,j,s,m,o){h=k(h,k(k(g^(i|~j),s),o));return k(h<<m|h>>>32-m,i)}function t(h){var i="",g,j;for(j=0;j<=3;j++){g="0"+(h>>>j*8&255).toString(16);i+=g.substr(g.length-2,2)}return i}var f=[],v,w,x,y,a,b,c,d;e=function(h){var i=h.length,g=0,j=0,s="",m;for(m=0;m<i;m++){var o=h.charCodeAt(m),u=null;if(o<128)j++;else u=o>127&&o<2048?String.fromCharCode(o>>6|192,o&63|128):String.fromCharCode(o>>12|224,o>>6&63|128,o&63|128);if(u!==null){if(j>g)s+=h.substring(g,j);s+=u;g=j=m+1}}if(j>g)s+=h.substring(g,h.length);return s}(e);f=function(h){var i=h.length,g=i+8;g=((g-g%64)/64+1)*16;var j=Array(g-1);for(l=0;l<i;l++)j[(l-l%4)/4]|=h.charCodeAt(l)<<l%4*8;j[(l-l%4)/4]|=128<<l%4*8;j[g-2]=i<<3;j[g-1]=i>>>29;return j}(e);d=271733878;a=1732584193;b=4023233417;c=2562383102;for(e=0;e<f.length;e+=16){v=a;w=b;x=c;y=d;a=n(a,b,c,d,f[e+0],7,3614090360);d=n(d,a,b,c,f[e+1],12,3905402710);c=n(c,d,a,b,f[e+2],17,606105819);b=n(b,c,d,a,f[e+3],22,3250441966);a=n(a,b,c,d,f[e+4],7,4118548399);d=n(d,a,b,c,f[e+5],12,1200080426);c=n(c,d,a,b,f[e+6],17,2821735955);b=n(b,c,d,a,f[e+7],22,4249261313);a=n(a,b,c,d,f[e+8],7,1770035416);d=n(d,a,b,c,f[e+9],12,2336552879);c=n(c,d,a,b,f[e+10],17,4294925233);b=n(b,c,d,a,f[e+11],22,2304563134);a=n(a,b,c,d,f[e+12],7,1804603682);d=n(d,a,b,c,f[e+13],12,4254626195);c=n(c,d,a,b,f[e+14],17,2792965006);b=n(b,c,d,a,f[e+15],22,1236535329);a=p(a,b,c,d,f[e+1],5,4129170786);d=p(d,a,b,c,f[e+6],9,3225465664);c=p(c,d,a,b,f[e+11],14,643717713);b=p(b,c,d,a,f[e+0],20,3921069994);a=p(a,b,c,d,f[e+5],5,3593408605);d=p(d,a,b,c,f[e+10],9,38016083);c=p(c,d,a,b,f[e+15],14,3634488961);b=p(b,c,d,a,f[e+4],20,3889429448);a=p(a,b,c,d,f[e+9],5,568446438);d=p(d,a,b,c,f[e+14],9,3275163606);c=p(c,d,a,b,f[e+3],14,4107603335);b=p(b,c,d,a,f[e+8],20,1163531501);a=p(a,b,c,d,f[e+13],5,2850285829);d=p(d,a,b,c,f[e+2],9,4243563512);c=p(c,d,a,b,f[e+7],14,1735328473);b=p(b,c,d,a,f[e+12],20,2368359562);a=q(a,b,c,d,f[e+5],4,4294588738);d=q(d,a,b,c,f[e+8],11,2272392833);c=q(c,d,a,b,f[e+11],16,1839030562);b=q(b,c,d,a,f[e+14],23,4259657740);a=q(a,b,c,d,f[e+1],4,2763975236);d=q(d,a,b,c,f[e+4],11,1272893353);c=q(c,d,a,b,f[e+7],16,4139469664);b=q(b,c,d,a,f[e+10],23,3200236656);a=q(a,b,c,d,f[e+13],4,681279174);d=q(d,a,b,c,f[e+0],11,3936430074);c=q(c,d,a,b,f[e+3],16,3572445317);b=q(b,c,d,a,f[e+6],23,76029189);a=q(a,b,c,d,f[e+9],4,3654602809);d=q(d,a,b,c,f[e+12],11,3873151461);c=q(c,d,a,b,f[e+15],16,530742520);b=q(b,c,d,a,f[e+2],23,3299628645);a=r(a,b,c,d,f[e+0],6,4096336452);d=r(d,a,b,c,f[e+7],10,1126891415);c=r(c,d,a,b,f[e+14],15,2878612391);b=r(b,c,d,a,f[e+5],21,4237533241);a=r(a,b,c,d,f[e+12],6,1700485571);d=r(d,a,b,c,f[e+3],10,2399980690);c=r(c,d,a,b,f[e+10],15,4293915773);b=r(b,c,d,a,f[e+1],21,2240044497);a=r(a,b,c,d,f[e+8],6,1873313359);d=r(d,a,b,c,f[e+15],10,4264355552);c=r(c,d,a,b,f[e+6],15,2734768916);b=r(b,c,d,a,f[e+13],21,1309151649);a=r(a,b,c,d,f[e+4],6,4149444226);d=r(d,a,b,c,f[e+11],10,3174756917);c=r(c,d,a,b,f[e+2],15,718787259);b=r(b,c,d,a,f[e+9],21,3951481745);a=k(a,v);b=k(b,w);c=k(c,x);d=k(d,y)}return(t(a)+t(b)+t(c)+t(d)).toLowerCase()};
var x = "random text";
alert(md5(x));
```

Comment: Could be a GET rather than a POST, since the result is idempotent. ;-)

Comment: @webdev_007: Note that WolfRevoKcats has happily assumed jQuery in the above, although you didn't mention it in your question and **jQuery  != JavaScript**. He's correct that Ajax is easiest with help from a library, though, whether it's [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ajax call to your server and have a webservice on the php side returning the information you need. Besides that? I don't think there is a way expect for refreshing.